# Implementing a Reader/Writer - Airline Reservation example

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am not new to C# but I am new to the Thread and Monitor classes. I'm trying to implement a "simple" reader/writer program using "Airline Reservation" as a base. This is a "homework question" taken from the book *C# How to Program (Introducing .NET and Web Services)* by Deitel.

Here is what I have so far:

This is the class that the Readers and Writers access synchronously. In the interests of brevity and space, I have removed most comments from these classes.

```
namespace Airline_Reservation
{
    // Represents a single airline reservation
    class Flight
    {
        private string reservation;

        public Flight()
        {
            reservation = "Airline: Unknown\nDate: Unknown\nDeparting Gate: Unknown\n";
        }

        public string Reservation
        {
            get { return reservation; }
            set { reservation = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString() { return Reservation; }

        // This is a required method
        public void StartReading() { Monitor.Enter(this); }

        // This is a required method
        public void StopReading()
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
            Monitor.Exit(this);
        }

        // This is a required method
        public void StartWriting() { Monitor.Enter(this); }

        // This is a required method
        public void StopWriting()
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
            Monitor.Exit(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reader:

```
namespace Airline_Reservation
{
    class Reader
    {
        private string name;
        private static int counter = 0;
        private readonly Flight flightInfo;

        public Reader(Flight info)
        {
            counter += 1;
            name = "Reader " + counter;
            this.flightInfo = info;
        }

        public Reader(Flight info, string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.flightInfo = info;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        // This is a required method
        public void QueryReservation()
        {
            flightInfo.StartReading();
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " reading flight reservation:\n" + flightInfo.ToString());
            flightInfo.StartReading();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the writer:

```
namespace Airline_Reservation
{
    class Writer
    {
        private string name;
        private static int counter = 0;
        private Flight flightInfo;
        private string airlineName;
        private string date;
        private string gate;

        public Writer(Flight flight)
        {
            counter += 1;
            name = "Writer " + counter;
            flightInfo = flight;
        }

        public Writer(Flight flight, string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            flightInfo = flight;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Airline
        {
            get { return airlineName; }
            set { airlineName = value; }
        }

        public string Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }
        }

        public string Gate
        {
            get { return gate; }
            set { gate = value; }
        }

        // This is a required method
        public void MakeReservation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " Making reservation . . .");
            string flightDetails = "Airline: " + Airline + "\nDate: " + Date + "\nGate: " + Gate + "\n";
            flightInfo.StartWriting();
            flightInfo.Reservation = flightDetails;
            flightInfo.StopWriting();
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " Completed reservation.");
            Console.WriteLine(flightDetails);
        }

        // This is a required method
        public void CancelReservation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " Cancelling reservation . . .");
            string flightDetails = "Airline: Unknown\nDate: Unknown\nGate:Unknown\n";
            flightInfo.StartWriting();
            flightInfo.Reservation = flightDetails;
            flightInfo.StopWriting();
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " Completed cancellation . . .");
        }
    }
}
```

I needed a place for the Writer to write into the Flight object so I added three private members to the Writer, adding the values from the main program class.

Here is my main program

```
namespace Airline_Reservation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Flight info = new Flight();

            Reader rdr1 = new Reader(info);
            Reader rdr2 = new Reader(info);
            Reader rdr3 = new Reader(info);
            Reader rdr4 = new Reader(info);
            Reader rdr5 = new Reader(info);
            Writer wtr1 = new Writer(info);

            wtr1.Airline = "Air Canada";
            wtr1.Date = "03/1/2020";
            wtr1.Gate = "J6";

            Thread rdrThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rdr1.QueryReservation));
            Thread rdrThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rdr2.QueryReservation));
            Thread wtrThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wtr1.MakeReservation));
            Thread rdrThread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rdr3.QueryReservation));
            Thread rdrThread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rdr4.QueryReservation));
            Thread wtrThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wtr1.CancelReservation));
            Thread rdrThread5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rdr4.QueryReservation));

            rdrThread1.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            rdrThread2.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            rdrThread3.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            rdrThread4.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            rdrThread5.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;

            wtrThread1.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            wtrThread2.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

            rdrThread1.Start();
            rdrThread2.Start();
            rdrThread3.Start();
            rdrThread4.Start();
            rdrThread5.Start();
            wtrThread1.Start();
            wtrThread2.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following, every time:

```
Reader 1 reading flight reservation:
Airline: Unknown
Date: Unknown
Departing Gate: Unknown

Writer 1 Cancelling reservation . . .
Writer 1 Making reservation . . .
```

... and then the program freezes and doesn't proceed. I suspect a deadlock somewhere but since this is my first program explicitly using threads, I don't know where to start.

Any advice or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is:

```
public void QueryReservation()
{
    flightInfo.StartReading();
    Console.WriteLine(Name + " reading flight reservation:\n" + flightInfo.ToString());
    flightInfo.StartReading();
}
```

This is going to call `Monitor.Enter(this)` twice on the same instance and is 100% guaranteed to deadlock. I'm guessing you meant:

```
public void QueryReservation()
{
    flightInfo.StartReading();
    Console.WriteLine(Name + " reading flight reservation:\n" + flightInfo.ToString());
    flightInfo.StopReading();
}
```

`Monitor` is for low-level thread synchronization and you don't seem to be synchronizing anything; you simply overwrite the same `Flight` instance in every thread. I'm guessing this is just dummy code and you actually want to do some stateful changes. In that case you would be better off with:

```
public void QueryReservation()
{
    lock(flightInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " reading flight reservation:\n" + flightInfo.ToString());
        // Do something to flightInfo here.
    }
}
```

`wtrThread1.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal` is not going to ensure the Writer runs before the Reader. That `Monitor.Pulse(this)` doesn't do anything either; `Pulse` is to notify another thread to inspect a shared reference and you aren't doing that. If you're trying to implement some kind of thread synchronization, like a Writer passing data to a Reader then waiting until the Reader is finished before passing more data, simply messing around with the Thread priority is not going to do that. Use `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead of trying to roll your own low-level synchronization.

Comment: Thank you. The first part of your answer actually fixed the deadlock issue and the program itself now runs fine. As to your other points, I was attempting to synchronize a single "reservation" (an object with a single string as a member). Several Reader threads are to be given unreserved access to this reservation. A Writer is supposed to "lockout" every other thread while it writes/clears the Flight object. I wrote this sample program based on the examples I saw in the book. I guess I was trying to understand what I was doing while I was doing it. Any advice?

Comment: Advice? Use [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) not threads; Tasks are more efficient and more generally useful. Threads are for “fire and forget” tasks you don't care if or when they run. Use `lock` not `Monitor`; `lock` does everything you are asking for.